# Troubleshooting Hot-Reload Issues in Angular Project After Upgrading from Earlier Version to 17

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, hot-reload

After the upgrade to Angular version 17, the hot-reload feature is not functioning as expected. Upon saving code changes, the updates are not reflected in the running application, impacting the development workflow. I need assistance in troubleshooting and understanding potential reasons behind the hot-reload issues in the upgraded project.

1)Check older version's hot reload and it's working but there's issue with the newer cli version.

2)Verified code changes are saved without syntax errors.

3)Reviewed Angular 17 migration documentation for specific instructions on hot-reload.

Answer (score 0):

You clould try to clean your cache.

`npm cache verify`

or

`npm cache clean`